# Why is Github Gist contributions aren't getting reflected to Github contributions?

Tags: github, gist

Shouldn't Gist contributions be connected to one's Github profile? Why this isolation? Weird!

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Comment: Well but this could bring a good lead for many developers who're more focused on the color pattern in github contribution chart.

Comment: This *is* a meta programming question. Hence the `github` and `gist` tags provided by StackOverflow.

Answer (score 9):

While every gist is a git repository, GitHub seems to like to keep them separate.

We can only assume this is intentional based on the fact that they provide separate gist profiles, and generally try to keep gist content separate from "normal" repositories.

Disclaimer: I am not a GitHub employee (only they can really answer this question).

Comment: I am not a fan of the disconnected nature of this. Are you aware of any open feature requests for this?